# How to update styles with the dom accessor in scalajs

Tags: scala.js

In scala js when I attempt to update the style of an element nothing happens and the style is set to an empty string.

e.g.
`elem.style.width = s"${card.width} px"`

pausing in a debugger in chrome will yield an empty string however the card.width will be set to 300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s"${card.width} px"` evaluates to `"300 px"`, which is not a valid CSS value because of the space. It should be `"300px"` (without space). See MDN for [more details on CSS values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units#Length_and_size). Otherwise you're doing it right.

Annoyingly, the JS DOM tends to silently swallow such errors (by design) instead of throwing exceptions.